# Trying to call a method in java but can´t get it to work

Tags: java

I'm new to programming in Java.
I have written a method in one class and I'm trying to call it to my other class. I don't know how to call it, because my way gives a compilation error.

Here is my method in one class:

```
    public static String checkWord(String [] input) {
    int points = 0;
    int words = 0;
    String result = null;

    for (int i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
        words++;

        if (input[i].equalsIgnoreCase(ENGLISH[i])) {
            points ++;
            result = "Correct " + points + " of " + words + " words";
        }
        else if (input[i].compareToIgnoreCase(ENGLISH[i]) > (ENGLISH[i].length() / 2)) {
            result = "Almost correct rätt. Correct answer was " + ENGLISH;
        }
        else {
            result = "Wrong. " + points + " of " + words + " words";
        }
    }


    return result;
}
```

And in the other class I'm trying to call it like this:

```
        String input = scanner.next();
    Words.checkWord(input);
```

But it doesn't work to write (input) only. What should i write to call my method?
The compilation error i get is:
'checkWord(java.lang.String[])' in 'wordhandler.Words' cannot be applied to '(java.lang.String)'

Very thankful for your help!

Comment: What's the actual text of the compilation error?

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow! Your question is incomplete, it is missing the compiler error. Please [edit] the question and include the compiler error. I also encourage you to read the error, it should give you a clear hint as to what the problem is.

Comment: His method takes a String[] while he only has a String.

Answer (score 2):

Your `checkWord` method takes a String array, while you only have a single string. To call that method, you must create a string array:

```
String[] array=new String[]{input};
```

and call the method with the new array: `checkWord(array);`

Alternatively, you could change the signature of `checkWord` to accept vararg parameters:

```
public static String checkWord(String... input) {
```

Vararg parameters are handled like arrays within the method, but you can call the method without wrapping the parameters in an array. In this case, your `checkWord(input)` call would be valid.